# Splitting a string in C

Tags: c, string

I need to split a string in C. I know I can use `strtok` but I am not really sure how to use it.

For example, I want to split this: `"L 90,120,130,140"` and I want to get the 'L' and, then, the integers separated by the `,` (comma).

Comment: Good question. But please show us what have you tried as well. Someone will try to rectify your mistakes.

Comment: http://www.teach-me-c.com/blog/breaking-string-pieces

Comment: You could always try searching SO for the many previous questions and answers about strtok.

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple delimiters in your `strtok`:

```
  char str[]="L 90,120,130,140";
  char *tok;
  tok = strtok (str," ,");
```

Then loop through and store them as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[]="L 90,120,130,140";
char *tok;
tok = strtok (str," ,");

while (tok != NULL) {
    if (isdigit(tok[0])) {
        int i = atoi(&tok[0]);
        printf("number %i\n",i);
    } else {
        printf("string %s\n",tok);            
    }
    tok = strtok(NULL," ,");
}
```

output:

```
string L
number 90
number 120
number 130
number 140
```

Can be further improved if floats are part of the string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char str[]="L 90,120,130,140";
  char *p ;

  p = strtok( str, " " ) ; // p is now pointer to 'L\0'
  printf( "first token: %s\n", p ) ;

  while( p = strtok( NULL, "," ) ) printf( "next token: %s\n", p ) ;

  exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strtok will destroy your string, you should use sscanf instead:

```
char s[2];
int a,b,c,d;
if( sscanf("L 90,120,130,140","%1s%d,%d,%d,%d",s,&a,&b,&c,&d)==5 )
  puts("reading was OK");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a supplement to the other answers.  Remember that strtok() is not reentrant.  If you are in a thread, use strtok_r.